# Angular 2 and Laravel - Restfull API can only be reached if set with a different port using artisan

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel-5, angular2-services

Im using CORs package for laravel my routes file is as follows

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function(){
        Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController', ['except' => [
            'create', 'edit'
        ]]);
    });
```

My Resource Controller is:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Course;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Requests\CourseForm;


    class CourseController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $courses = Course::all();
            return response()->json(['courses' => $courses]);
        }

        /**
         * @param CourseForm $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function store(CourseForm $request)
        {
                $course = new Course();
                $course->author = $request->input('author');
                $course->name = $request->input('name');
                $course->description = $request->input('description');
                $course->price = $request->input('price');
                $course->save();
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Course saved']);

        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            $course = Course::find($id);
            return response()->json(['course' => $course]);
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(CourseForm $request, $id)
        {
            if($request->ajax())
            {
                $course = Course::find($id);
                $course->author = $request->input('author');
                $course->name = $request->input('name');
                $course->description = $request->input('description');
                $course->price = $request->input('price');
                $course->save();
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Course updated']);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            $course = Course::find($id);
            $course->delete();
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Course removed']);
        }
    }
```

and my angular service is :

```
    import {Http, Headers, Response} from "@angular/http"
    import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"
    import {ICourse} from "../interfaces/ICourse"
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class Api {
        // only works if I execute php artisan serve --host=www.test.io --port=8001
        apiUrl: string = "http://www.test.io:2736/api/courses/";
        headers: Headers = new Headers;
        courses$: Observable<ICourse[]>;
        private _coursesObserver: Observer<ICourse[]>;
        private _dataStore: {
            courses: ICourse[]
        };

        constructor(private _http: Http) {
            this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            this.courses$ = new Observable<ICourse[]>(observer => this._coursesObserver = observer).share();        
            this._dataStore = { courses: [] };
        }

        public createCourse(course) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this._http.post(this.apiUrl, course, {
                    headers: this.headers
                }).map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
                        (res) => {
                            resolve(res);
                            console.log('api succeeds');
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            //alert('error');
                            reject(error);
                        }
                    );
            })
        }


    }
```

I am running the web app using MAMP on a mac, which works fine however posting to my service/api doesnt work unless i execute:

```
 php artisan serve --host=www.test.io --port=8001
```

the port number doesnt really matter it basically just has to be any port but 80.. I cant for the life of me figure out why this is, Am running the site in MAMP so all php should be gettng executed as normal as well as all HTTP requests as its all running on PORT 80 except mysql which is on 3306, but regardless I cant see why I need to run 2 servers simultaneously (artisan and mamp) just to make RESTfull API calls on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We should only reached with different ports because Angular and Laravel haven't run at same port.